# Overlay line plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlay, linegraph

I've created a multiple line graph using ggplot2, where each line represents a year that is plotted against month (click link below).  Volume is represented on the y-axis.

[image: http://imgur.com/3Rwdjyi]

Here is the code I used to plot the figure above:

```
ggplot(data=df26, aes(x=Month, y=C1, group=Year, colour=factor(Year))) + 
    geom_line(size=.75) + geom_point() +    
    scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul",
        "Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels=comma) + 
    scale_colour_manual(values=cPalette, name="Year") +    
    ylab("Volume")
```

**Question:** How do I also include another line to the plot that represents the mean volume within each month with the ability to modify the line thickness and color of that mean line?  So far, all of my attempts at producing the right code have been unsuccessful (most likely due to my relative newbie status using R).  Any help is much appreciated!

**Edit:** Dataframe df26 is provided below (as requested by a commenter):

> ```
> Year  Month   C1
> 2010  Jan NA
> 2010  Feb NA
> 2010  Mar NA
> 2010  Apr NA
> 2010  May NA
> 2010  Jun NA
> 2010  Jul NA
> 2010  Aug 183.6516764
> 2010  Sep 120.6303348
> 2010  Oct 85.31007613
> 2010  Nov 13.7347988
> 2010  Dec 20.93950545
> 2011  Jan 13.35780833
> 2011  Feb 14.16910945
> 2011  Mar 9.786319721
> 2011  Apr 41.24848885
> 2011  May 122.3014387
> 2011  Jun 422.4012809
> 2011  Jul 539.8569592
> 2011  Aug 527.6301222
> 2011  Sep 385.8199781
> 2011  Oct 201.7846973
> 2011  Nov 27.91934061
> 2011  Dec 7.919004379
> 2012  Jan 10.22724424
> 2012  Feb 10.64391791
> 2012  Mar 88.06585438
> 2012  Apr 124.0320675
> 2012  May 325.1399457
> 2012  Jun 465.938168
> 2012  Jul 567.2273488
> 2012  Aug 459.769634
> 2012  Sep 333.8636373
> 2012  Oct 102.0607986
> 2012  Nov 23.18822051
> 2012  Dec 15.64841121
> 2013  Jan 7.458238256
> 2013  Feb 4.34972039
> 2013  Mar 26.2019396
> 2013  Apr 38.82781323
> 2013  May 257.0920645
> 2013  Jun 357.594195
> 2013  Jul 383.2780483
> 2013  Aug 456.469314
> 2013  Sep 319.3616298
> 2013  Oct NA
> 2013  Nov NA
> 2013  Dec 17.01748185
> ```

Comment: Where's the data.  It is expected you provide `df26` or a mock up of it.

Comment: Hi, Tyler.  Dataframe df26 is provided now.  Thanks for reading my post!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to calculate the means. Then you can plot them.
Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df26means <- df26 %>%
    group_by(Month) %>%
    summarize(C1 = mean(C1, na.rm = T))
```

Then add it to your plot:

```
ggplot(data=df26, aes(x=Month, y=C1, group=Year, colour=factor(Year))) + 
    geom_line(size=.75) + geom_point() + 
    scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                              "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels=comma) + 
    scale_colour_manual(values=cPalette, name="Year") + 
    ylab("Volume") +
    geom_line(data = df26means, aes(group = 1), size = 1.25, color = "black")
```

I'd recommend using `annotate` to add a nice piece of text on the plot identifying that line as the mean line. To get it in the legend, you'd probably need to set `df26means$Year = "Mean"`, convert `df26$Year` to a character, `rbind` the two dataframes together, then convert `Year` to a factor. The plot code would be simpler, but the data wrangling is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thank you, Gregor!  However, calculation of the means is affected due to the fact that I have NA values in the dataframe.  I tried adding to summarize(C1 = mean(C1), **na.rm=TRUE**), but this doesn't appear to ignore the NA values.  As Tyler Rinker above commented, I will include the dataframe df26 to my original post.

Comment: Use `summarize(C1 = mean(C1, na.rm=TRUE))` instead.  You put it in the wrong spot.

Comment: @soitgoes Didn't realize you had `NA`s. Thanks for sharing the data (`dput()` is a really nice way to share, it makes it copy/pasteable... for next time). As Tyler says, be careful where you put your `na.rm`. It's an argument to `mean`, not to `summarize`. Updated the code in the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks, Gregor! That makes sense now (na.rm as an argument to mean). I tried to run the code with the suggested modification, but now I get **Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Year' not found**--is there an easy fix for this? Again, thanks for your help (as you can tell, I'm pretty new to r)!

Comment: @soitgoes Oops! The last `geom_line()` was inheriting the `group = Year` aesthetic from the initial call. Resetting it for that layer makes everything work (see edited answer).